# BlocProvider not finding Generic Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have the below generic Bloc which I am trying to use.

```
class ManageFeedbackBloc<T extends IContribute>
extends Bloc<ManageFeedbackEvent, ManageFeedbackState> {}
```

I used the below provider to create it:

```
void _navigateToContributionPage(
  BuildContext context, FeedbackCategory category) {
final userFeedbackBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserFeedbacksBloc>(context);
final manageFeedbackBloc = ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>(
    repository: ManageFeedbackRepository());

final manageFeedbackDestination =
    BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>>(
  create: (context) => manageFeedbackBloc,
  child: ManageFeedbackPage<DoctorFeedback>(),
  lazy: false,
);

userFeedbackBloc.monitorFeedbackChanges(
    BlocProvider.of<ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>>(context));

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => manageFeedbackDestination));
```

}

The above code crashes on this line:

```
userFeedbackBloc.monitorFeedbackChanges(
    BlocProvider.of<ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>>(context));
```

I get the error:

> Another exception was thrown: Error: Could not find the correct
> Provider<ManageFeedbackBloc> above this
> ContributionSelectorPage Widget

If I also try to skip the above and use BlocBuilder, I get the same error. Please see the code below:

```
 class ManageFeedbackPage<T extends IContribute> extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ManageFeedbackBloc<T>, ManageFeedbackState>(
      listenWhen: (_, currentState) => currentState.isListenerState,
      buildWhen: (_, currentState) => !currentState.isListenerState,
      listener: (context, state) async {
        if (state is ManageFeedbackPromptUpdate) {
          _promptActionAlert(
              context,
              'Modification',
              'Êtes vous sûr de vouloir modifier ce retour d\'expérience ?',
              ManageFeedbackUpdateFeedback());
          return;
        }
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'manage_feedback_page - UnImplemented State: Tried to implement listening state to ${state.toString()}');
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ManageFeedbackLoading) {
          return _getLoadingState();
        }

        return _getLoadedState(context);
      },
    );
  }
 }
```

Is it that generic bloc is not supported?

***I am using flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0***

Comment: Can you show where you call or which build context you are trying to call that bloc? this may happen because you are using the incorrect context, which the context is not under the bloc of the tree, to read the bloc

Comment: I am calling it right after the BlocProvider.

Comment: > I am calling it right after the BlocProvider.

That's the problem, exactly what @CbL has mentioned - using the wrong context. Probably you need to use Builder() under BlocProvider just to create another context and be able to access the BLoC. Please, provide the code where exactly you are trying to access the BLoC.

Comment: I have included the relevant code. So If I try to navigate to the other screen with BlocBuilder I still have the same issue. Which made me think that generic BloCs are not supported for some reason. Is that the case?

Comment: just want to confirm if the ManageFeedbackPage is a child of a BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc<T>>? As I can only see the Consumer part.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I found the problem:

```
final manageFeedbackDestination =
    BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>>(
  create: (context) => manageFeedbackBloc,
  child: ManageFeedbackPage<DoctorFeedback>(),
  lazy: false,
);
```

BlocProvider type should not specify the generic type just the type of the BloC without the generic.

```
final manageFeedbackDestination =
    BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc>(
  create: (context) => manageFeedbackBloc,
  child: ManageFeedbackPage<DoctorFeedback>(),
  lazy: false,
);
```

This worked for me BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc> instead of BlocProvider<ManageFeedbackBloc<DoctorFeedback>>.